# get randomly record of specific entity in mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql, database

i am facing a little bit issue in mysql database. i have two table like user and post.

user table
[image]

Post table

[image]

mysql Query

```
SELECT user_id,name FROM `post` where user_id IN(1,3,4); // 1,3,4 id of user from user table
```

Above mysql query working fine.But Now i want to got  maximum three record of each user randomly.Result of above query is fine

```
user_id name
      1 one
      3 two
      1 three
      1 four
      1 five
      4 somthing
      4 test
      1 some body
      3 help
      1 beauty
```

how i got randomly three record of each user like if user_id = 1 then randomly three record of this user fetch from database.
Let suppose one user has 1000 post and other user has also 500 post. i want to show only maximum 3 post of each user with the help of database mysql query.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.
We don't need to see 1000 rows. 12 will probably do.

Comment: Try With this ....... SELECT user_id, name FROM post WHERE user_id IN(your values) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,3

Comment: @Zaibi you restrict the rows i don't want this.
Suppose user_id IN(1,3,4) // pick up randomly maximum three post of each user not three rows of post table
so maximum rows 3*3 = 9   // as three user like 1,3 and 4.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one i think so it will work

SELECT user_id,name FROM `post` where user_id IN(1,3,4) order by user_id rand() limit 0,2

Answer (score 0):

**ORDER BY RAND()** combined with **LIMIT** is useful for selecting a random sample from a set of rows

Here is solution i recommend , You have to Use **UNION** in your query or you may use **LOOP** to change the **user_id** value for next turn.

i have test it with UNION

```
SELECT user_id, name FROM post WHERE user_id = 1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3
UNION
SELECT user_id, name FROM post WHERE user_id = 3 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3
UNION
SELECT user_id, name FROM post WHERE user_id = 4 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3
```

this time we only have three values for condition but if you have to do it for more user_id values you should use LOOP for changing the condition value.

Comment: if there are 1000 users then we are going to unite 1000 queries?

Comment: i alredy mentioned , for more conditional values (Users) we have to use a LOOP to change it and finally we will get desired result.

Comment: if thousand user exist then thousand time loop run ? it takes time

Comment: @Haseeb you can use this method for this time only to solve your problem, when you or I will find a better solution, surely we will discuss here.

Comment: @Haseeb If you think this answer is providing the required solution for this scenario you may click on the tick mark to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this query hope you achieved your requirements.

```
 SELECT
      product.product_id,
      tb.order_product_id,
      tb.rank,
      product.date_added
    FROM product
      LEFT JOIN (SELECT
                   product_id,
                   order_product_id,
                   (SELECT
                      COUNT(*)
                    FROM order_product AS aopin2
                    WHERE aopin.product_id = aopin2.product_id AND aopin2.order_product_id < aopin.order_product_id) AS rank
                 FROM order_product AS aopin) tb
        ON product.product_id = tb.product_id AND tb.rank < 3
    ORDER BY product.product_id,date_added DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Correlated sub-queries might come handy. Below query will return 3 records for each of the users in the `post` table

```
SELECT `post`.id, `post`.user_id, `post`.name
FROM `post`
WHERE 3 > (
    SELECT count( * )
    FROM `post` AS `post1`
    WHERE `post`.`user_id` = `post1`.`user_id`
    AND `post`.`id` > `post1`.`id` 
)
ORDER BY `post`.`id` DESC
```

To get them random entries,

```
SELECT `post`.id, `post`.user_id, `post`.name
FROM `post`
WHERE 3 > (
    SELECT count( * )
    FROM `post` AS `post1`
    WHERE `post`.`user_id` = `post1`.`user_id`
    AND `post`.`id` > `post1`.`id` 
)
ORDER BY RAND()
```